# Fill list with another object list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Is there any convenient way to move/copy id's from `objList` to `idList`?

With java 8 streams maybe?

```
public class SomeObject() {
  private Long id;
  private String value;

  public Long getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
  public String getValue() { return value; }
  public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
public void doSomething() {

  List<SomeObject> objList = fillWithManyObjects(); //getting objects with values
  List<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();

  objList.forEach(obj -> flightSlotIdSet.add(obj.getId));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a simple stream

```
 List<Long> idList = objList.stream()
     .map(SomeObject::getId)
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for this but i couldn't find/remember it.